# Как поменять язык intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять язык этого окна на русский?
P.S И как оно называется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Надо во время выбора шаблона проекта выбирать платформу `.NET Framework`, а не `.NET Core`

Comment: Отличное у Вас решение. Отказаться от современной платформы в пользу legacy ради пары буковок. Вау

Comment: Во время обучения не имеет значения легаси это иль нет...

Answer (score 0):

Следуй первой части инструкции [Установка локализованных файлов IntelliSense для .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/localized-intellisense)

Только вместо 5 пункта

> В открытой папке моникера создайте вложенную папку. Имя папки указывает, какой язык будет использоваться. В следующей таблице приводятся различные варианты.

Не создавай не какую папку, а перенеси файлы с заменой. Только что проделал и всё работает